# Prove that absolute value of function is less or equal to integral of function squared

Tags: integration

I was solving some exercises in my calculus textbook when I stumbled upon this one:

Given $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ continuously differentiable with $f(0) = 0$, prove that

a) $|f(x)| ≤ \int_{0}^{1} |f'(x)|\, dx$ for every $x$ in $[0,1]$.

b) $|f(x)| ≤ \int_{0}^{1} |f'(x)|^2\, dx$ for every $x$ in $[0,1]$.

I managed to solve (a) but I'm uncertain of how to solve (b) since if $f(x) = x/2$ ($f(0)=0$) then for $x = 1$, $ |1/2| \le \int_{0}^{1} |1/2|^2\, dx =\int_{0}^{1} |1/4|\, dx = 1/4 $ which is incorrect. Is the textbook wrong, or have I made an error somewhere?

Comment: Does your textbook use the same variable $x$ as a free variable and for the dummy variable of the integral? If that's the case I suggest you find another textbook.

Comment: Your counterexample is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part (b), the question should be corrected as $|f(x)|^2\leq\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|^2 dx$, which is a consequence from (a) and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.